# external images can't be loaded by ajax

Tags: css, ajax, external

I have a index.php page. It contains a navbar with some links. Through ajax, I made a small loading process, here you can see the code of a link:

```
$('#link1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#target').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $('#spinner').fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'content/1.php',
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(html) {
                    $('#target').empty();
                    $('#target').append(html);
                    $('#target').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

You can see, the external php content page (1.php) will load inside the "target" div. Now the problem is that the "1.php" is formatted by an external css, loaded into the "1.php" with this code:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1css/style.css">`

But when I lunch the index.php, I see only the text conten from 1.php, not it images. Where is the mistake? May I load external css for 1.php by ajax? I can send you the folder, so you can see it more specificly...thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the ajax call only parses HTML, not styles. Your images may not be appearing because the styles that apply to your loaded content don't exist in the page you're loading the content into (or the relative paths are different).

If you need to load the styles as well, it's probably worth appending the relevant CSS file to the head of the page you're loading the content into - just make sure to check relative file paths.

Comment: MassivePenguin is correct. See this site for an example: http://www.phpied.com/files/jinc/Luis/test.html for how to load an external CSS file

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your response. I belive I'll put my style into the "head" tag...thanks a lot...I'll try and let you know...thanks

Comment: I lunch my chrome browser..I see the console section, this is the message: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) "....

Comment: Also, just noticed the butchering of my original answer... this isn't what I replied with at all any more :(